# Symfony2/Memcached integration

Tags: symfony, memcached

I was following a blog post (link no longer available) and added memcached to services.yml

```
parameters:
    memcached.servers:
      - { host: 127.0.0.1, port: 11211 }

services:
    memcached:
        class: Memcached
        calls:
            - [ addServers, [ %memcached.servers% ]]
```

Then in my controller:

```
$memcached = $this->get('memcached');
```

Looks very pretty. If I can get past `500 - You have requested a non-existent service "memcached"`!

The test code from php connects to memcached without any troubles. Done cache:clear, cleared cache manually - doesn't help.

Where should I look?

Comment: Try first to add these to your `app/config/config.yml`. If it works, then your original `services.yml` file is not loaded.

Comment: You were right Adrien, config.yml wasn't included into config.yml. If you make that as an answer I'll accept it. Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Adrien was right in his comments - services.yml file isn't used by default. You have to explicitly include it in config.yml

Comment: Want just to note `app/config/services.yml` is loaded by default as of Symfony 2.7 (I think probably 2.6 as well)