# How to clear cache (memcached) in symfony 2

Tags: php, symfony, caching

I have to clear two caches on my website - `elastic cache`, and `memcached`. I have all the keys needed. How can I do that? Because as far as I know symfony doesn't have built in mechanisms to achieve that.

I know how cache works more or less, but I have no idea how can I do that, where to clear this cache, where to generate keys...I haven't found anything on this topic.

How can I do that?

Comment: see this:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11540171/symfony2-memcached-integration

Comment: Ok, service and parameters are set, but...how do I clear cache now? Is memcached service built in?

Comment: no its not...may be this can helh http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8449345/symfony-2-cacheclear-bug

Comment: I'm connecting with external memcached instance, not the symfony's internal !